# RecourceDictionary inside a Windows Phone Class Library

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

What I need to do is to define different DataTemplates and Style into a Recource Dictionary in a Windows Phone Class Library and use them **WITHIN** that library. I have tried many things so far that didn't work. Any one ever did this before?

What I tried so far:

1. Put the Styles under Themes > generic.xaml and try to use it in code by `Resources["StyleName"] as Style`. Resources is empty, thus the style was not loaded properly. The .xaml's Build Action was set to Resource.
2. Put a RecourceDictionary.xaml file into the Class Library root folder and try to use it in code by `Resources["StyleName"] as Style`. Resources is empty, thus the style was not loaded properly. The .xaml's Build Action was set to Resource.
3. Tried to create the Style xaml IN-CODE even though this is not optimal and still gives me errors on parsing the xaml - I do **NOT** want to use this solution anyway.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the Resources table always **empty** in the code and how can I set its `Resources.Source` properly? Everything I tried thrown an exception so far.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include some code to illustrate exactly what you've tried? Have you included your Generic.xaml or ResourceDictionary.xaml as a MergedDictionary in your App.xaml?

Comment: I don't think that code will do any good. As I said what I need to do use that `Style` inside my Class Library. Windows Phone Class library does not have an App.xaml by default. I have created one on my own and used merged dictionaries there but it still does not work.

Comment: You can use the `Style` in your Class Library. It will not be picked up until runtime. At runtime, assuming you've added the merged dictionaries to your App.xaml, locating the resource via `Resources["StyleName"]` should work.

Comment: It doesn't work. The `Resources` table is empty as I mentioned before.

Comment: Hmm, you said you created an App.xaml on your own? Do you mean you created an App.xaml file in your Class Library? If so, this is not what I was describing. What I mean is that you need to add your Styles.xaml as a merged dictionary in the App.xaml for your app project (not your Class Library). Resources are parsed/merged/generated at runtime, which implies that you need something runnable, which is your app.

Comment: Now that makes sense. So I cannot define custom Styles for a class library that contains more than one controls, is that correct?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. You can add as many `Style`s as you want into your library's Styles.xaml. Do you mean a default `Style` for a Templated Control? Each Templated Control should have no more than one default `Style` (e.g. `<Style TargetType="library:YourControl">`). Maybe some sample code would help clarify what problem you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Because I wasted a lot of time on this I will post how I finally solved it.

So what I have is the following:

- A Windows Phone Class Library.
- A Resource Dictionary Under /Themes Folder with build action set to Resource and nothing under custom tool. NOTE: THE RD IS IN THE SAME PROJECT - INSIDE THE CLASS LIBRARY

  - The Resource Dictionary is called test.xaml and inside it I have a converter with several styles.

Now in order to be able to use `aStyle = (Style)Resources["StyleName"];` in my code I had to load it in the class library constructor as following:

```
Resources.Source = new Uri("/CLASS_LIB_NAME;component/Themes/test.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

This was the only way I could make this work without getting any kind of exceptions.

Of course someone could replace `Resources.Source` with `MergedDictionaries` to load more .xaml style files.. I just needed to load one for this control.